# overrideMaterial and renderObject() geometry mismatch

Tags: three.js

I can't figure out how to overcome a potential limitation of the three renderer and was hoping someone might have a good design of how best to overcome the issue.

Say you create a scene with mesh objects and apply a basic material to them. Because you've created the objects using the basic material, the geometry will never have normals generated for it as  the basic material does not need it. (Along with most of the other attributes).

Let's say I now want to render the scene again (for a post process), but this time I use an override material on the renderer. This overide material is a shader material and it does require normals.

When the scene is being rendered, the renderer will apply the override material, however it will throw invalid pointer errors because the new shader requires normal attributes but the mesh geometry does not have any because it was created with a basic material.

So how would I be able to achieve this second render pass? The first render has to use basic materials as anything more is overkill and could slow down the application. The second pass must contain normals as its rendering important information for a post process effect. I can't call needsUpdate on the materials or geometry each time as its part of the render loop and having to rebuild them each frame will be hugely expensive.

So how might I approach this? Is it even possible? Obviously the one answer would be that I have to use a phong material to begin with so that the normals are generated. But that could be really expensive in complex scenes that only require a basic shader and material.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

---

EDIT

---

Forgot to mention that this second render was being done in a plugin. And its not always rendered before the scene. The post process effects can be added and removed at random.

Comment: can't you just call "computeVertexNormals" and/or "computeFaceNormals" once?  sorry, i am just guessing.

Comment: I don't think so... From what I understand, just before the object is rendered to the screen it calls the initMeshBuffers function. This essentially creates the array buffers which later get used in the materials and shaders. The geometry by default has normals. But inside the initMeshBuffers function the __normalArray variable never gets set. The reason is because just before it fills them, it looks at the material. If the material is basic it decides that the __normalArray  buffer should not get filled - even if the geometry has normals.

Comment: The only way to rebuild the arrays would be to call needsUpdate on the geometry and assign the new material. But as you can imagine, if I keep calling needsUpdate each frame it will kill the application

Comment: well wouldn't it be sufficient to just call it ones? After _normalArray is initialized, you are fine? Also you could just edit three.js maybe to fill the normalArray?

Comment: I think it might be an idea to just not use Basic Materials and instead create my own shader material that uses a modified basic shader. I guess this would circumvent the issue.

Comment: Hmm, sounds good. btw maybe you should still report this issue on github?

Comment: Sure. I'm never sure when to post on the issues list. Often I find that things that are issues to me don't seem to qualify. Anywho... will give it a try :0)

Comment: As an experiment/work-around, render the geometry once with, say, `meshLambertMaterial`, and then switch to `MeshBasicMaterial`. What is the post-processing effect you are using? Do a performance test to see if your assumptions are really true.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to figure out a solution. Its probably not the most elegant, but it works. I added the below code just before the render call. Unfortunately the function initWebGLObjects is called before the plugins so any updates to the geometry are missed. It means that I have to manually call initWebGLObjects again in the plugin when the object material is basic. Ideally I would want to call renderer.updateObject but that function is private....

```
//If its a basic material on a mesh, we need to make sure the object is re-built with normals
//This is to make sure when any of the post processes are rendered they have all the vertex 
//attributes they need.
var obj = webglObject.object;
if ( objectMaterial instanceof THREE.MeshBasicMaterial && obj.geometry.__builtNormals === undefined )
{
    var geometry = obj.geometry;
    geometry.__builtNormals = true;                 
    geometry.buffersNeedUpdate = true;
    geometry.uvsNeedUpdate = true;
    geometry.normalsNeedUpdate = true;

    //material.needsUpdate = true;                  
    obj.material = material;
    _renderer.initWebGLObjects( scene );
    obj.material = objectMaterial;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

No need to go through all the trouble. Indeed the initMeshBuffers take into account the presence or lack of normals, but they can be computed successfully after the fact. I made a basic test with an application here and after appling the MeshBasicMaterial to my model I simply called

```
geometry.computeTangents();
```

Then built a new ShaderMaterial and applied that as my new material. Worked like a charm, hope that helps.

Edit: I should mention this may be in conjuction with the aforementioned `computeVertexNormals()` and `computeFaceNormals()` depending, oh and that the shader material uses normals for my normal map.

Comment: just to clarify - did you render the object and then apply the material? Or was this all done before the first render call? Thanks!

Comment: Ah you caught me, I indeed did this all before the first render :/ My apologies, however maybe there is still a simple solution to be found here. This time I render one frame with an advanced shader, then swap out the basic version, then at anytime there after I can swap in the advanced shader and it renders correctly. Sound reasonable?